# How can I read socket stream until newline?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I have a Node.js server + Unity (.NET 3.5) app that I ensure communication in between through sockets. I am having an issue while receiving data from Node.js server to C# socket client.

I would like my C# client to read socket streams until a linebreak (`/n`) is found. This is how I ensure data flow from C# to Node.js server, since there is an NPM module called *split* which ensures reading the buffer line by line.

The following is my code, and I would highly appreciate if you could suggest me solutions to achieve the mentioned way of receiving data:

Here, I connect to Node.js server without issue:

```
private Socket ClientSocket;
private byte[] _receiveBuffer = new byte[8142];

public string hostname;
public int port;

public void onnectClient()
{
    ClientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    ClientSocket.Connect(hostname, port);
    ClientSocket.BeginReceive(_receiveBuffer, 0, _receiveBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), null);
}
```

The following is current `ReceiveCallback`,:

```
private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
{
    int received = ClientSocket.EndReceive(AR);
    byte[] recData = new byte[received];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(_receiveBuffer, 0, recData, 0, received);

    string resultString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(recData);

    currentlyReceivedData = JsonUtility.FromJson<ReceivedData>(resultString);

    ClientSocket.BeginReceive(_receiveBuffer, 0, _receiveBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), null);
}
```

**UPDATE 1:**

Instead of the code above, now I use TcpClient and StreamReader, but for some reason, while loop does not continue:

```
    private void ListenForData()
{
    try
    {
        socketConnection = new TcpClient("localhost", 6670);
        Byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];
        while (true)
        {

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(socketConnection.GetStream()))
            {
                string line;
                // Read and display lines from the file until the end of 
                // the file is reached.
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    Debug.Log("line");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SocketException socketException)
    {
        Debug.Log("Socket exception: " + socketException);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just want to point out that it's not guaranteed that when you call `EndReceive` you will receive the full data at one go. You have to handle the senario when the size of the full data is larger than your buffer, or just getting partial data because of slow network.

Comment: SwiftingDuster, this is actually I guess my problem! At some point, the flow from Node.js server just blocks and I do not anymore receive any data :/

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need to use all of the options available for [`Socket`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket?view=netframework-4.7.2), I'd suggest instead you use the `TcpClient` class. Once you're connected, you can call [`GetStream()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.getstream?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_Sockets_TcpClient_GetStream) on it to receive a [`NetworkStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream?view=netframework-4.7.2)<sup>1</sup> you can pass to a [`StreamReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Once you're there, you can just call `ReadLine()` (or moral equivalents) to retrieve each complete line. This allows you to ignore many of the realities of working with "raw" TCP such as having to reconstruct/save buffers to reflect the reality that it's not messaging but a stream of bytes.

`ReadLine` can cope with any normal form of line endings, `\n`, `\r` and `\r\n` included.

---

<sup>1</sup>Note that you could just construct one from your existing `Socket` as an alternative. But I try to use the simpler options unless I need the complexity of the more complex one.

Comment: Hello Damien_The_Unbeliever, thanks for the reply! Could you please check my updated version above? For some reason, the while(true) loop does not continue...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you look at this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/07/09/system-io-pipelines-high-performance-io-in-net/

That can save you quite some trouble!

If you can't use System.IO.Pipelines, you can still study the sample how to read from a socket until you reach new line!

Comment: Hello Nick! Thanks a lot for the answer, this really looks like that I am looking for. I should say I am quite new to .NET framework and it is a huge change in terms of way of thinking after Node. 

Could you please also suggest me how I should initiate reading socket buffer using this solution? Do you think BeginReceive is the way?

Comment: See @Damien_The_Unbeliever's answer - using a TcpClient is a better idea in your case.